# mapping controls to viewmodel

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I know this is probably a newbie questions but again, I'm fairly new to WPF. Right now most of my textboxes, labels, textblocks, etc... are hidden from xaml.cs code behind based on what the logic is. I wanted to know if there a way to map my controls from my xaml file to the viewmodel?

```
<TextBlock Name="txtBlockName" Text="Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="15,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" />
<TextBox Name="txtName"  Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Visibility="Hidden" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Binding for this (you have one-way and two-way binding, in this case you are probably looking for two-way binding).

Also look here: [the msdn tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx) and you can keep a [xaml binding cheat sheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2009/02/02/wpf-xaml-data-binding-cheat-sheet.aspx) :).

Some basic example. What I did was set the datacontext, in this case I set it to the MainWindow class (itself), however you can easily set it to your viewmodel. Then I bound the value of `MyFoo.MyString` to the text property of the textbox.

The button and the other textfield is to illustrate that the two way binding works (in this case it is even default).

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding MyFoo.MyString}" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,41,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,70,0,0" Name="textBox2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" IsEnabled="False" Text="Init" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Create a class `Foo` with following definition:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

And in your MainWindow code behind, you have this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Foo MyFoo { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyFoo = new Foo() { MyString = "Hello" };

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = MyFoo.MyString;
    }
}
```

This is just a quick and dirty example. I think you can figure the rest out, or else: just look around, there is a **lot** of information about data binding in WPF.

Comment: so with my edit above, i would have to put mode=twoway for both of them? Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: right, I understand what you have right there. And what you provided is what I'm using right now but I want to move to MVVM to get away from using "xaml.cs" and use ViewModel. Does this make sense?

Comment: so again I've modified the code with Visiblity = "Hidden" ... on my xaml.cs, I can make them visible by setting Visibility = Visiblity.Visible. I'm just going in circle because I'm using MVVM but at the same time, is it good practice to use "xaml.cs" to do the hiding/showing? If it's not good practice, how do I incorporate this to using VM?

Comment: You can use for example Data Triggers to do showing / hiding controls when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the viewmodel is set as the DataContext of your control. Then you can use something like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PropertyName, Mode=TwoWay}" Name="txtName"  Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

to bind Text of your TextBox to the PropertyName of the viewmodel